# OP-AMPs in a Loop

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, feedback

I am trying to understand what an OP-AMP looping is used for?
For example, this is the circuit that I am dealing with:
[image]

I didn't connect the entire pins, but I hope I made the point accross. I have a voltage reference IC (ADR441), outputing a 2.5 DC voltate, and I beleive the circuit generates two higher voltage DC values.

I am having a hard time understanding how the circuit works ! 
For example, what happens at voltage V1, V2, V3?

If V1 keeps adding up, then how does that work? Isn't it that V1 is tied to a 2.5 reference voltage? Then it's value shouldn't change ! But then how does V3 increments?
To me it looks like OP-AMP 1 is in a non-inverting amplifer configuration, where Vout ~ Vin(1+R2/R1). And, OP-AMP 2 is kind of similar but it is more like a voltage follower configuration. I would appreciate some help on what happens to V1, V2 and V3 over time, and why?

Comment: Have you done the current calculations yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Howland current pump - a type of constant current generator: -

[image]

Op-amp 2 in your circuit is, the same as the smaller of the two op-amps shown above. Out1 is, ostensibly the current output but it also shares this with R6 and R7 - as to what out1 and out 2 are used for I don't know because there is no detail in your question.

[Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf) is a decent article on it.

Comment: Andy, thanks a lot. This makes perfect sense now. This is exactly what my circuit it diong.